# How do you find out which commit a file mode change came from?

Tags: git, blame

I'm familiar with using `git blame` on the commandline to show which commit changed a particular line of a file.

Is there a similar function to show which commit last changed the file "mode"/flags?  E.g. setting or unsetting the executable flag.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `git log` with the `--summary` flag and search the output for mode changes:

`git log --summary -- path/to/file`

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---summary):

> --summary
>
> Output a condensed summary of extended header information such as creations, renames and mode changes.

Answer (score 5):

With some `grep` and `head`:

```
$ git log --summary --format=%h | grep 'mode change' -m1 -B2 | head -1
```

It will print `SHA-1` of last commit that contained `mode change`. If you want to track a specific file:

```
$ git log --summary --format=%h <FILE> | grep 'mode change' -m1 -B2 | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --summary --pretty=oneline | grep -B1 '^ mode change'
```

will give output like:

```
$ git log --summary --pretty=oneline | grep -B1 '^ mode change'
2edfdb6dd322d31818998fb4fb588394d57fd1b4 Remove executable flag
 mode change 100755 => 100644 path/to/file
--
8b8c539cfaeda7f15be53839561dcae4f4a69f5e Make the file executable
 mode change 100644 => 100755 path/to/file
```